# Getting key error while calling a column in dataframe with any function

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting an error when i am trying to read a column named 'Not polished' from the data frame , any function related to that column is giving the following error .. tried everything , changed the name in original dataset also but getting the same error again and again

---

```
KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Not polished'
```

Comment: You say you are trying to read a column named ***"Not finished",*** but you get a KeyError complaining that ***"Not polished"*** is not an existing key.  That discrepancy seems like an obvious potential explanation of your problem.

Comment: Sorry it was a typing error , the column name is "Not polished" only , even if I am trying to get a normal sum of the float values present its showing the same error

Comment: We can't help without knowing the actual column names your dataframe.  No guessing please!